# Can't access static IP ubuntu server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, static-ip

I am running an Ubuntu server 14.04 LAMP server within Hyper-V. When using DHCP, everything works. The moment I change it to a static ip by modifying the contents of /etc/network/interfaces to resemble:

```
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static  
    address 192.168.0.247  
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    network 192.168.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.254  
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.2
```

and reset the VM, I can no longer view web pages hosted by the machine, nor can I connect to it using ssh. The server can access google using

```
curl www.google.co.za
```

and can ping any device on the network. Any other device can also ping the server. The only problem is that Ubuntu server suddenly seems to refuse all connections.

Any help in clearing up the problem would be appreciated.
 Thanks.

Comment: Can you post output of ifconfig while using DHCP? ... I have a suspicion that your gateway may be the culprit.

Comment: and addiional pls. inform us which kind of network adapter do you use with Hyper-V (I'm not sure with Hyper-V, but with VMWare, you can define a bridging adpater, a NAT-Adapter, a Host-only-adapter)